# Manual partitioning and EFI nightmare

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

*Specs: Lenovo Ideapad-320
SSD - 120gb/4gb
CPU -AMD A6*

I think I need your wisdom.

So, I think I messed up with my **efi** bootloader or something.
I was using a debian based distro and I tried to distro hop to Ubuntu Mate. I decided to try **manual partitioning** as I have used it before with success. I encountered problems so I tried deleting all partition in my disk an making a new partition table with the right partitions (efi,/,swap,/home). Everything I tried was a failure as any distro I tried installing showed up some kind of error at the end regarding partitions.enter image description here
I even tried boot repair from live usb installer but nothing.
Funny thing is every usb installer allows me to open up **"UEFI Options"** which leads me back to my BIOS info normally. I tried enabling UEFI/Legacy support on BIOS but same results.
Attached are my current drive config and an error on efi partition.

**Any help on how to fix this please?**

[gparted info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAL5c.png)

[trying to dlete sda3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYWB5.png)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Your question is about Zorin which is not an official Ubuntu flavour. So unfortunately it is not supported on this site. You can use their help forum or https://unix.stackexchange.com/. But did you partition the disk during install? If not you probably should. That is just guessing though.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes I did and when it failed I switched to Ubuntu Mate live usb. I tried  during installation but also had already made the partitions in case it fixed the problem

Comment: You should put the Ubuntu Mate info in the posting, and post the errors it produces.  Also posting a link to the boot repair report will help.  What kind of partition table did you select, gpt?  There are others available but who knows if they'll work.